# refactor Html.LabelFor, EditorFor, ValidationMessageFor into partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to refactor view form code to avoid copyPaste. But it's not working. Razor don't allow to write

```
@model System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
```

and

```
@Html.Partial("Item", model => model.EmpName)
```

Old code, that working:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" style="border: 0;">
                @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.EmpName)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field" style="border: 0">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.EmpName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.EmpName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" style="border: 0;">
                @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Email)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field" style="border: 0;">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Email)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

After refactoring not working:

Item.cshtml:

```
   @model System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" style="border: 0;">
                @Html.LabelFor(expression)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field" style="border: 0">
                @Html.EditorFor(expression)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

New code:

```
 @Html.Partial("Item", model => model.EmpName)
 @Html.Partial("Item", model => model.Email)
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own HtmlHelper extension method, something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var group = new TagBuilder("div");
    group.InnerHtml = html.LabelFor(expression).ToString();
    //more formatting and controls here
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(group.ToString());
}
```

This will allow you to write:

```
@Html.MyEditFor(m => m.Name)
```

The drawback of this approach is that you won't be able to inline HTML because this is not a view. However it does allow you to set up a standard control layout.

Comment: hehe, beat me by 18 seconds. answer deleted and +1. :)

Comment: thats an interesting thought. makes me wonder. @PaulKeister, do you think he ought to write a custom helper that uses a predicate? does it have any advantage over just accessing the Model and passing 'sub-model' to his partial? if so, I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: Instead of deleting your answer, can you add a bit more example code to show how ValidationMessageFor, EditorFor, etc. can be invoked regardless of the model type of the main view?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found. Thanx to @Paul.

Item.cshtml:

```
 @model MyClientCustomValidation.Models.LabelEditorValidation 
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" style="border: 0;">
                @Model.Label
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field" style="border: 0">
                @Model.Editor
                @Model.Validation
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Which has model:

```
public class LabelEditorValidation
{
    public MvcHtmlString Label { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Editor { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Validation { get; set; }     
}
```

And inside form:

```
@Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.EmpName)
@Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.Email)
```

Where MyEditorFor is

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return html.Partial("Item", new LabelEditorValidation() { Label = html.LabelFor(expression), Editor = html.EditorFor(expression), Validation = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression) });
    }
```

Comment: this solution works for `model.Field` where `Field` is not `int`. For `model=>model.EmpName` and `model=>model.Email` works, but for `model=>model.Age` failes. Exception [Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688143/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension) occures

Comment: The problem is that int isn't an object (it can be boxed, but the compiler won't infer a boxing). In order to solve this, I've parameterized the value type, see my revised answer. By the way, I like the way you pass the rendering on to a view, rather than build HTML in code.

Comment: By the way, you can simply return the partial view, since partials return MvcHtmlStrings.

Comment: ok, thanx @Paul. After changing from `Expression<Func<TModel, object>>` to `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` everything works great