# Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My model:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Id")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(18, 150)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

In my view:

```
 @Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.EmpName)
 @Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.Email)
 @Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.Age)
```

My custom helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression)
    {
        var partial = html.Partial("Item", new LabelEditorValidation() { Label = html.LabelFor(expression), Editor = html.EditorFor(expression), Validation = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression) }).ToString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(partial);
    }
```

Item.cshtml - partial view:

```
 @model MyClientCustomValidation.Models.LabelEditorValidation 
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label" style="border: 0;">
                @Model.Label
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field" style="border: 0">
                @Model.Editor
                @Model.Validation
            </td>
        </tr>
```

LabelEditorValidation - model for Item.cshtml:

```
      public class LabelEditorValidation
{
    public MvcHtmlString Validation { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Label { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Editor { get; set; }
}
```

I have exception

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions

on line:

```
    var partial = html.Partial("Item", new LabelEditorValidation() { Label = html.LabelFor(expression), Editor = html.EditorFor(expression), Validation = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression) }).ToString();
```

The exception occures when   `@Html.MyEditFor` is called for `model.Age`.

```
 @Html.MyEditFor(model=>model.Age)
```

But it not occures when `@Html.MyEditFor` is called for `model.EmpName` and `model.Email`.
That's because `model.EmpName` and `model.Email` are strings but `model.Age` is `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make your helper a little more generic and get rid of the `object` argument:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
{
    var partial = html.Partial(
        "Item", 
        new LabelEditorValidation 
        { 
            Label = html.LabelFor(expression), 
            Editor = html.EditorFor(expression), 
            Validation = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression) 
        }
    ).ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(partial);
}
```

Now your expression won't break as there won't be unnecessary boxing.

Comment: magic! I changed to more generic and exception fly away. I don't understand why but it works.

Answer (score 10):

*For the Google search users*,
Just don't call any `Html.XyzFor` methods like this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property***.MyMethod()***)
```

Use `view models` instead, to apply that `MyMethod` on the given property.