# Templates can be used only for field access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This Line of Code is causing the below error.

Code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(y => y.Data.Select(z => z.Name).First().ToString());
```

Error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

This is in a Razor MVC4 View.

Can this be re-written or can I not do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688143/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension)

Comment: The message is pretty straight forward and explanative. And there is pretty great answer in the link I've provided above: "**For the Google search users, Just don't call any Html.XyzFor methods like this `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Property***.MyMethod()***)`
Use view models instead, to apply that MyMethod on the given property.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Html.DisplayFor(y => y.Data.Select(z => z.Name).First().ToString())
```

That Will Show The Value Instead of the property name.